# Zoom Video SDK - Jwt auth fails

Tags: java, jwt, zoom-sdk

We have implemented an API within our backend that generates a jwt token according to the specifications indicated in the documentation.
When we pass the token to the VideoSDK web ui-toolkit, in some cases we get the error:

zoomsdkjsonpcallback1({
"status": false,
"errorCode": 124,
"errorMessage": "Verify JWT Failed: The token was expected to have 3 parts, but got 1."
})

We have already verified that the token contains all the necessary fields in the payload.

Sometimes a token that fails on some subsequent attempt works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include your JWT Token so we can see what the issue is? (Pass in dummy values for your Key and Secret.)

Comment: Problem solved, tks

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

It's a problem related to signature final encoding, so by using:

```
Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(signedBytes);
```

instead of

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedBytes);
```

My bad.

authentication works